# How to evaluate a postfix expression using character stack using ASCII conversions

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation

The code is implemented using ADT by including the "stack.h" user defined header file.

The header file has code for stack operation.
I am getting the outputs as weird symbols because of improper ASCII conversions.

What changes should i make in the code to get the correct output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include "stack.h"
using namespace std;

void posteva(char postfix[])
{
    stack s;
    int i=0;
    while(postfix[i]!='\0')
    {
        char x=postfix[i];
        if(isdigit(x))
        {
            s.push(x);
        }
        else
        {
            int op1=s.pop();
            int op2=s.pop();
            int res;
            switch(x)
            {
                case '+':
                    res=op1+op2;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    res=op1-op2;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    res=op1*op2;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    res=op1/op2;
                    break;
                case '%':
                    res=op1%op2;
                    break;  
                case '^':
                    res=op1^op2;
                    break;              
            }
            s.push(res);
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"\n\nRESULT :"<<s.pop();
}

int main()
{
    char postfix[20];
    cout<<"\n\nEnter the postfix : ";
    cin>>postfix;
    posteva(postfix);   
}
```

Comment: For example. I entered the postfix expression as "23+" and the result was 'e'.

Comment: Is that the *only* input you give? What does `stack` store? `int` values? What happens if an operation result in a value larger than `9`?

Comment: The [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) values for `'2'` and `'3'` are `50` and `51` respectively. `50 + 51` is `101` which happens to be the ASCII value for `'e'`.

Answer (score 1):

The [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) values for `'2'` and `'3'` are `50` and `51` respectively. `50 + 51` is `101` which happens to be the ASCII value for `'e'`.

You're adding the ASCII *encoded* values instead of the digits.

To convert a digit to its `int` equivalent, take a look at that [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) again. Don't you see some pattern when it comes to digits? Experiment with doing e.g. `'3' - '0'` and see what you get.

When you get it, you will have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you push digits as characters (which is OK) but you use them as if they were `int`s. If you would like to keep only characters on the stack, you would need to perform conversions on the way in and on the way out:

```
int op1=s.pop() - '0';
int op2=s.pop() - '0';
...
s.push(res + '0');
```

This approach is problematic, because you would have no easy way to deal with multi-digit numbers. You would be better off converting your stack to a stack of integers, and modifying your code to work with multi-digit inputs.

**Note:** `^` is a XOR, a bitwise operation. Since all the other operations are arithmetic, I suppose that you wanted `'^'` to signify raising `op1` to the power of `op2`. In this case you should use `pow` function from the math library.

Comment: I performed the conversions but it is working for the results <9.  How can i get the right values of result >9.

Comment: This is what I explained in the paragraph that starts with "This approach is problematic ..."

Comment: So there is no way I can use a char stack to get the right result?

Comment: @NirajWagh There is, but it would be very much akin to hammering a square peg into a round hole.